# Getting search results to display ul for text field being inputted into

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery with classes instead of ID's because I will be in a situation where I have identical text fields generated by php depending on a users input. When a user starts typing, a loader appears and then on the fourth key stroke results will appear in an unordered list via php/ajax. The issue I am having is that when a user types into text field one, unordered lists appear for both text field 1 and 2 when it should only appear for whichever text field they are typing in.

I tried something like this but it yields no results and console doesn't give me any errors.

```
$(".result").closest("ul").html(data);
```

Here is the full code (html)

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    $(".loader").show();
    if (input.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert-ajax.php',
            data: {
                name: input
            },
            success: function(data) {

                if (!data.error) {
                    //$(".result").html(data);
                    $(".result").closest("ul").html(data);
                    $(".loader").hide();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    if (input.length < 1) {
        $(".loader").hide();
        $(".result").html("");
    }
});

$(".result").on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).closest(".result").siblings("input").val($(this).text());
});

});
```

PHP which echoes the ul and li

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $search_result = $row['short_desc'];
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li>" . $search_result . "</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're selecting all `.result` in your update, you can use the context in jQuery.ajax to target the specific element

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert-ajax.php',
        context: this,
        data: {
            name: input
        },
        success: function(data) {

            if (!data.error) {
                $(this).html(data);
                $(".loader").hide();
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: thank you Musa. I tried your code and no results display at all.

Comment: After looking over your code again I notice no `ul`s in it, can you show them

Comment: @ Musa, I have updated the original question with the php which echoes out the ul and li.